# Regex for passwords: At least 3 digits/lower/upper

Tags: php, regex, validation, passwords

I'm trying to create a regular expression that validates following conditions

1. Min * length
2. Min * lower case
3. Min * upper case
4. Min * special characters

I already have this

```
^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%^&+=])(?=\S+$).{8,}$

^(?=.*[0-9]) // At least 1 digits
(?=.*[a-z]) // At least 1 lower case
(?=.*[A-Z]) // At least 1 upper case
(?=.*[@#$%^&+=]) // At least 1 special character
.{8,}$ // length 8
```

The problem is that I need to validate at least 3 digits/lower/upper on any place on the string.

What do I have to add to my RE to make it possible? I was trying to use `(?=.*[a-z]{3,})` but that only allows consecutive lower case char...

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/tP0bQ5/1

Comment: Allow users to use the [passwords / phrases](https://xkcd.com/936/) they desire.

[Don't limit passwords.](http://jayblanchard.net/security_fail_passwords.html)

Comment: Closed while typing answer >< You can work with [negated class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) in between: `^(?=(?:\D*\d){3})` for three digits, `(?=(?:[^a-z]*[a-z]){3})` for three lowers... [finish and test it here](https://regex101.com/r/vR5pE3/2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following regex

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%^&+=])(?=(?:.*[\da-zA-Z]){3})\S{8,}$
```

---

[Regex explanation here.](https://regex101.com/r/tP0bQ5/2)

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Answer (score 0):

There are easier ways to do this than with a regex.  For example, min length can be resolved with `len(password) >= min_length`.  Likewise, a minimum number of lower case letters can be resolved with `sum(password.count(let) for let in ["a", "b", "c" ... "z"]) >= min_lower_case`.